# Clone a subdirectory from github using git

Tags: git, github, subdirectory, git-clone, git-sparse-checkout

In git I want to download a folder from a Github repository and add it to a subdirectory in my repo like so:

repo/folder/subfolder/

repo/folder/subfolder/clonedfolder //cloned folder from git hub

But I get the path directories as well which I don't want.

repo/folder/subfolder/folder/folder1/folder2/clonedfolder

This what I have tried

```
repo/folder/subfolder$ git init

repo/folder/subfolder$ git remote add -f origin git@github.com:repo/repo.git

repo/folder/subfolder$ git sparse-checkout init

repo/folder/subfolder$ git sparse-checkout set clonedfolder

repo/folder/subfolder$ git sparse-checkout list
- clonedfolder

repo/folder/subfolder$ git pull origin develop
```

Is this possible in git?

Answer (score 0):

Git isn't geared toward this. Reason being, that whenever you fetch from a repo, your `.git/objects` folder contains all changes to all files in the repo.*

If you have a choice, I'd separate concerns into [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), which are more-or-less independent git repositories linked together using a parent project (with a `.gitmodules` file).

Then you can just use symbolic links to make the directory structure you want.

For example:

```bash
mkdir parent-project ; cd parent-project
git init
mkdir .my-git-root-folders
git submodule add https://example.com/child.git .my-git-root-folders/child
ln -s .my-git-root-folders/child/path/to/subfolder childmodule
git add childmodule
git commit -m 'Add and link child module'
```

After this you can access `childmodule/some-file` as if you were accessing `<child repo>/path/to/subfolder/some-file`.☥

Git will track symbolic links.‡

#### Footnotes:

- ***** Except in cases of shallow clones, which only include the latest revisions for each reachable HEAD. Each file's state is still recorded, however.
- **☥** If your code doesn't *specifically* test for symbolic links.
- **‡** Windows is known to have problems with symbolic links; you need Administrator access to even create them. For best results, use either Linux, Mac OSX, Windows WSL, or a Linux virtual machine.